# jQuery aplicar função em todas as div com mesmo nome

Tags: jquery

Olá,
Eu tenho um html com vários campos que repetem a mesma div, quero aproveitar essas divs para aplicar uma função jQuery em todas elas. Qual seria a melhor forma de fazer isso? contas quantas vezes a classe se repete e aplicar um for each?

Comment: Usar um classe não seria mais simples? poderia por uma porção desse código?

Comment: `$('.nome-da-classe').each(function(){ ...` - acho que é isso que procuras. mas podes mostrar o HTML que tens e o que queres fazer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu utilizaria [each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/)

```
$('div').each(function(){
     //Código da função
});
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 1):

Para aplicar a função para todas as `divs` com mesmo `name` basta fazer o seguinte:

```
$("[name=nomeDiv]").evento(function(){
  //Código da função
});
```

Nesse caso, a função será aplicada a todas as `divs` com `name` igual ao definido na função.

Ou, se preferir, pode definir uma `class` comum para todas essas `divs` e aplicar a função pela `class` definida:

```
$(".nomeClass").evento(function(){
  //Código da função
});
```

Com isso, a função será aplicada a todas as `divs` que tiverem a `class` definida.

**Exemplo utilizando o atributo `name`:**

```js
jQuery(function($){
  setTimeout(function() {
  $('[name=divTeste]').fadeOut('fast');
  }, 4000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Ocultando as Divs com mesmo name em 4 segundos:</p>

<div name="divTeste" style="border:1px solid">
div com name igual
</div>
<br>
<div name="divTeste" style="border:1px solid">
div com name igual
</div>
<br>
<div name="divTeste" style="border:1px solid">
div com name igual
</div>
<br>
<div name="novaDiv" style="border:1px solid">
div com name diferente
</div>
```

No exemplo acima, todas as `divs` que possuam mesmo `name` definido na função serão ocultadas em 4 segundos.

**Exemplo utilizando uma `class` comum para todas as `divs`:**

```js
jQuery(function($){
  setTimeout(function() {
  $('.divTeste').fadeOut('fast');
  }, 4000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Ocultando as Divs com mesma class em 4 segundos:</p>

<div class="divTeste" style="border:1px solid">
div com class igual
</div>
<br>
<div class="divTeste" style="border:1px solid">
div com class igual
</div>
<br>
<div class="divTeste" style="border:1px solid">
div com class igual
</div>
<br>
<div class="novaDiv" style="border:1px solid">
div com class diferente
</div>
```

No exemplo acima, todas as `divs` que possuam a mesma `class` definida na função serão ocultadas em 4 segundos.